# Giving equal chance for each element i to be added to a list L if Ri > T is verified

Tags: python, algorithm, probability

With the following simple algorithm, if the test `if Ri > T:` is used then we get more or less 30 elements in L and 70 elements in U, this is ok since the value of T is set to 0.7.

Now if I want to add a constraint which is: additionally to the fact that elements i that are put L are those for which Ri is > T, I want also that L do not contains more than B=20 (that is, I want that at the end, when i=n, the size of L will be more or less B=20).

But the problem is that, if I replace the test `if Ri > T:` by `if Ri > T and len(L) < B:`, then the elements that are put in L are more likely to be among the first elements i that we browse (that is, an element i = 87 for example will never have a chance to be in L). But I want that all the elements from i = 1 to n will have equal chance to be in L (not advantaging only the first elements).

Note: the condition that `Ri > T` for putting the element in L, should not be removed from my code. This is important for me: only elements for which $Ri$ was higher than T at time i, are allowed to be in L; and len(L) should not exceed B (more or less).

```
import random

T = 0.7 # or any value T in ]0,1[
n = 100 # or any value n > B
B = 20 # or any value B < n

L = []
U = []

for i in range(1,n+1):
   xi = input("please give a new data x")
   Ri = 1. - random.random() # normally it is Ri = 1. - Proba(xi) depending on xi, but lets simplify using random() ...
   if Ri > T:
      Pay 1 euro and buy yi the label of xi
      L.append((xi, yi))
   else:
      U.append(xi)


print len(L), L
print
print len(U), U
```

Comment: How about if, after the loop has run, len(L) < 20, randomly pull elements from U into L until len(L) = 20?

Comment: It would really help if you explained what `L` `U` and `B` are. As far as variable naming goes, this code is terrible.

Comment: @torquestomp no if an element i was put in U, it should not be removed from U and put in L, because the Ri of this i was less than T (this have a meaning for me), only elements for which Ri was higher than T at time i, are allowed to be in L.

Comment: @JoelCornett what don't you understand in the code ? it is very simple ! The variable name is arbitrary it has a meaning for me which is complicated to be explained here. The algorithm is this simple one, I don't know what you find complicated; B is a budget (a sort of upper bound on the size of the list L), and L and U are just some lists ...

Comment: @gotto this was just a simplified algorithm where I just used values i of the loop as elements to be put in the lists. Actually, these are some input values $x_i$ at each time $i$ (instead of i itself), and $R_i$ is a random variable of $x_i$ (Probability(x_i)). To make it simple I expressed the algorithm as I did.

Comment: @gatto the input come one by one at each time i. The user will give you the value of x_i at each time i, and if then Ri is 1-P(x_i), and if this value Ri is higher than T, x_i is allowed to be added to L. So, what you said makes no sense here.

Comment: @gatto lenght of L should not exceed B all the time of course. Imagine that it is costly to put an element in L, so I we can just put at maximum B elements in L (these elements should have their Ri > T). So, you can not put all the elements having Ri > T in L then remove some of them such that the size of L become B. Note: I just updated the code to make you understand more exactly what it is.

Comment: What I don't understand is A) the purpose of your code, and B) what exactly your end result is. For example, "when i=n, the size of L will be more or less B=20" makes no sense. Which is it, more, or less?

Comment: If you don't mind my saying so, I get the feeling that you are making this way more complicated than it actually is. If you explained the result you're trying to achieve, it might help find a solution.

Comment: @JoelCornett (A) it is really complicated to explain the real purpose of the code for you, and it is useless (it will not help you to answer the question), the algorithm that I gave is already very simplified. (B) the end result is L have a size B and the elements xi that we put in L are those for which Ri was higher that T, but every possible element in {x0, x1, ..., xn} should have a chance to be put in L if its Ri is higher than T. That is, DO NOT just "take the first B elements having Ri>T and put them in L and forget about the rest of elements xi".

Comment: @JoelCornett and the "more or less" is just because you will not get exactly the desired number of elements in the list since you use random() which do not generate a perfect uniform random. That is, if you do: `for i in range(100): if random()>0.5: a++ else: b++; you'll not get exatly 50 elemnts in a and 50 in b, you'll sometimes get a=48 and b=52, and some times a = 53 with b = 47, ... etc. So "more or less 50 ..."

Comment: @gatto we want that the len(L) never exceed the budget B (imagine that I'll ask you to give me 1 euro each time you put something in L, then if you have 20 euros you can not ask me to put more elements in L). For replacing elements in L it is not ok, I'll edit my code now to show you why it is not possible (5 minutes).

Comment: @gatto I'have edited the algorithm just before `L.append(...)`. Let me know if you understood why it is not possible to replace elements in L (since you already paid 1 euro to get their label, right?).

Comment: @gatto Can you provide a code for what you are saying "I'm going to buy this, but I'll first look at alternatives", based on my previous code, please ? It will allow me to better understand what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with the comments suggesting this isn't as well specified as it could be.  If I'm reading it correctly, though, you could use a kind of [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling):

```
def some_accept(value_stream, p, max_num_to_accept):
    accepted = []
    passed = (v for v in value_stream if random.random() < p)
    for i, value in enumerate(passed):
        if len(accepted) < max_num_to_accept:
            accepted.append(value)
        else:
            replace_i = random.randint(0, i)
            if replace_i < max_num_to_accept:
                accepted[replace_i] = value
    return accepted
```

which gives

```
>>> some_accept(range(100), 0.7, 10)
[34, 26, 30, 16, 22, 38, 32, 86, 33, 12]
>>> some_accept(range(100), 0.05, 10)
[16, 17, 83, 95]
```

Now, this may violate your "cost" condition about `L`, in that we do potentially "add" more than 10 elements, but I'd argue that every time I replace an element you'd have to give a coin back.

A quick sanity check of the frequency distribution looks okay (it's very easy to make an off-by-one error resulting in a bias):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in range(100):
    s = sum((Counter(some_accept(range(10), 0.25, 4)) for i in range(10**3)), Counter())
    x, y = zip(*sorted(s.items()))
    ax.plot(x,y)

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to first figure out which list you want to add the element to, by selecting a random number and comparing it with B/n; then create the item with a random value which is in the range for list in question:

```
for i in range(n):
  rt = random.randint(1,n)
  if (rt <= B):
    r1 = random.uniform(T, 1)
    # add x1 with r1 to L
  else:
    r1 = random.uniform(0, T)
    # add x1 with r1 to U
```

By the way, subtracting a random number in the range `[0, 1)` from 1 does not invert the probability; there's still a 30% probability of it being `> 0.70`. (It does change the range to `(0, 1]`, but that's not significant most of the time.) I suspect that's not what you wanted, but it's hard to know; anyway I changed it so that 70% of the values fall into the range for `L`. Adjust the above as necessary.

Comment: 1) I don't see where do you compare with B/n in your code. 2) what is small b ? 3) what is "# add x1 with r1 to L" doing ? Can you please complete the code so that I can understand what you want to say. Thanks.

Comment: @shn, b was a typo. fixe. I'm comparing a random number in [1,n] with it. As for the rest of the code, `add x1 with ri to L` is just as handwaving as your code's `L.update(xi, yi)` and means the same thing. If you complete your question, I'll be able to complete my answer :). The point is that it cannot be important to you what the value of `ri` is since you don't keep that value around; it cannot influence the future use of `L` or `U`. But it evidently matters to you, so it must be the case that you do actually use it.